# High level code architecture for react project

Tags: reactjs, web-frontend

I'm planning to build a web app where users get personalized information on administrative procedures (visas/company creation etc) including a service to fulfil the selected procedure.

Broadly speaking, there will be a list of procedures, each qualified through a multi step questionnaire leading to the selection of a 'form'.

How do I take this up from a project org perspective, keeping in mind the scalability of the project.

Ideally X super users should be able to create N procedures (including step selection logic) leading to P forms.

TIA from Paris.

Still in conceptualisation phase.

Comment: At what level do you need the info, like for example, the tech use like React, Reac router, Formik for forms, useQuery for api data cache etc
or its about setting up React app structure with App, Http, Language context with routes

Comment: I should have precised, sorry. I'm looking for any existing libraries that can help speed up dev time on the questionnaire part. And a top level component map.